# Avs FastSimpleImport - Import all images

Tags: import, importexport, product-images, avs-fastsimpleimport

i'm using the Avs_FastSimpleImport extension to import my products from an csv file. Im building up my product array according to the documentation of the extension, found [here](http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/products.html)

I manage to import the base_image for now. But i have three images (base_image, small_image & thumbnail) and dont find the right solution how to import the other two. According to this, it should be an array, or what:

[image]

my code for images, so far:

```
            '_media_attribute_id'     => !empty($media_attribute_id) ? $media_attribute_id : null,
            '_media_image'            => isset($product['image']) ? $product['image'] : null,
            'image'                   => isset($product['image']) ? $product['image'] : null,
            'small_image'             => isset($product['small_image']) ? $product['small_image'] : null,
            'thumbnail'               => isset($product['thumbnail']) ? $product['thumbnail'] : null,
```

My Question is how to build up my array to be able to import and set the thumbnail and small_image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two options for this. It's more comfortable to use nested arrays (see http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/options.html: "Support Nested Arrays for Import"), you can then use arrays inside the *media** attributes like this:

`'_media_attribute_id' => array(77, 77, 77),
'_media_image' => array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg',
'_media_is_disabled' => array(1, 0, 0),
'_media_position' => array(1, 2, 3),
'_media_lable' => array('Image 1', 'Image 2', 'Image 3'),`

If you don't want to use nested arrays, you can have seperate arrays for the additional rows per product as described in http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/. Just don't provide a "sku" value (just `null`instead) for the additional rows.

Comment: thanks, works great but, there is none of the images set as base, thumbnail or small image

Comment: after testing a bit around i fixed it by my self. the trick was to set the image, small_image & thumbnail images in addition to the values above:                 'media_gallery'           => 0,
                'image'                   => isset($product['image']) ? $product['image'] : null,
                'small_image'             => isset($product['small_image']) ? $product['small_image'] : null,
                'thumbnail'               => isset($product['thumbnail']) ? $product['thumbnail'] : null,